# Select from many to many table query

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have some tables:

**Sessions**
*SessionID* int PK
*Created* datetime 
*SiteId* int FK

**Tracking_Parameters**
*ParamID* int PK
*ParamName* nvarchar

**Session_Custom_Tracking**
*SessionID* int FK
*ParamID* int FK
*ParamValue* nvarchar

**Site_Custom_Parameters**
*SiteID* int FK
*ParamID* int FK
*ParamKey* nvarchar

**Sessions**: Contains the unique session id for a visitor and the time they entered the site.

**Tracking_Parameters**: Contains a list of things that you may want to track on a site (i.e. Email Open, Email Click, Article Viewed, etc.)

**Site_Custom_Parameters**: For a particular site (table not shown), declares the key value for a Tracking_Parameter (i.e. the key to look for in a query string or route)

**Session_Custom_Tracking**: The link between a session and a tracking parameter and also contains the value for the parameter's key when it was found by my application.

Question:

I want to select session id's where for these particular sessions, there is a record in the Session_Custom_Tracking for two different ParamID's. I want to find sessions where a user both opened an email (paramid 1) and clicked (paramid 3) a link in that email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join to the same table twice:

```
SELECT S.SessionID
FROM Sessions AS S
JOIN Session_Custom_Tracking AS SCT1
ON SCT1.SessionID = S.SessionID
AND SCT1.ParamID = 1
JOIN Session_Custom_Tracking AS SCT2
ON SCT2.SessionID = S.SessionID
AND SCT2.ParamID = 3
```

An alteranative that might be easier to read (because it more closely matches the way you describe the problem) is to use `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
SELECT S.SessionID
FROM Sessions AS S
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Session_Custom_Tracking AS SCT1
    WHERE SCT1.SessionID = S.SessionID
    AND SCT1.ParamID = 1
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Session_Custom_Tracking AS SCT2
    WHERE SCT2.SessionID = S.SessionID
    AND SCT2.ParamID = 3
)
```